Reactjs Jest test failing with undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
I am trying to write a simple test case where I am trying to test a register form rendered on the page with all its fields in a Reactjs project but getting this typeError undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)), I tried to update the mocking of useSearchParam, but no luck, Please help
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import RegisterPage from "./RegisterPage";
import { useAuth } from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

// Mock dependencies
jest.mock("react-hook-form", () => ({
  useForm: jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useNavigate: jest.fn(),
  useSearchParams: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue([new URLSearchParams(), jest.fn()]), // Return a mock array
  useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ pathname: "/register" }),
}));

jest.mock("../../hooks/useAuth", () => ({
  useAuth: jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock("react-google-recaptcha", () => jest.fn(() => <div>ReCAPTCHA</div>));

describe("RegisterPage", () => {
  const mockRegister = jest.fn();
  const mockNavigate = jest.fn();
  const mockGetValues = jest.fn();
  const mockCaptchaRef = { current: { getValue: jest.fn(), reset: jest.fn() } };

  beforeEach(() => {
    useForm.mockReturnValue({
      handleSubmit: jest.fn((fn) => (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fn();
      }),
      register: jest.fn(),
      getValues: mockGetValues,
      formState: { errors: {} },
    });

    useAuth.mockReturnValue({
      user: null,
      register: mockRegister,
    });

    jest.spyOn(React, "useRef").mockReturnValue(mockCaptchaRef);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("renders RegisterPage", () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    render(
      <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
        <RegisterPage />
      </Router>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText("Register")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("Name")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("Email")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("Password")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("Confirm Password")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("Address")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText("ReCAPTCHA")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText("Register")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText("Already a user?")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

